# Dropdown is always returning 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am hiding and showing div based on the Dropdown selection. but dropdown is always returning 0 value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rel_status').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'never') {
      $("#pre_rel").hide();
    } else {
      $("#pre_rel").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="relationship_status" id="rel_status">
  <option value="-1">Please Select</option>
    <option value="never">Never Married</option>
    <option value="divorced">Divorced</option>
    <option value="waiting">Waiting for Divorce</option>
    </select>


<div id="pre_rel" style="display:none;">
  hi
</div>
```

php code : except rel_status, all other fields are working fine. It's saving 0 in database.

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $about_me= $_POST['about_me'];
    $relationship_status= $_POST['relationship_status'];
    $pre_relationship=$_POST['pre_relationship'];
    $weight=$_POST['weight'];
    $height=$_POST['height'];
    $eye_color=$_POST['eye_color'];
    $hair_color=$_POST['hair_color'];
    $language_first=$_POST['language_first'];
    $language_second=$_POST['language_second'];
    $ethnic_group=$_POST['ethnic_group'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("update  user set about_me='$about_me',rel_status='$relationship_status',pre_relationship='$pre_relationship',weight='$weight',height='$height',eye_color='$eye_color',hair_color='$hair_color',primary_language='$language_first',second_language='$language_second',ethnic_group='$ethnic_group' where user_id='".$_SESSION['userid']."'");

$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $about_me,$relationship_status,$pre_relationship,$weight,$height,$eye_color,$hair_color,$language_first,$language_second,$ethnic_group);
$stmt->execute();
```

$stmt->close();

Comment: Seems to work fine.

Comment: Could be because you are not using === sign to check , you can try that too

Comment: Your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hu1znzgo/. I've also updated your question to show that what you posted works.

Comment: yes, HTML code is working fine. but when I want to save selected value in database, it return zero.

Comment: But you've posted none of the code you use to do that, so how can we help you?

Comment: alert(this.value); is returning the correct value. Check the code that is inserting values to DB, could be something wrong in that.

Comment: @j08691  I posted php code also. all fields are working fine. except rel_status

Comment: Can you post a variable dump of $_POST?

Comment: @j08691 means ? all variable except relationship_status are working fine.

Comment: I'll ask again, can you post a variable dump of $_POST?

Comment: @j08691 did not understand. please explain

Comment: In your script, add either `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump()` and update your question with the results it displays.

Answer (score -4):

the select value is not accessible by value attribute. you need to loop the options and chase the selected flag. (select can have more then a one option selected if you use multiple attr)

```
var val = null;
document.getElementById('mySelect').options.forEach(function(o) {
  if(o.selected) val = o.value;
});
```